# Ruby creating Hash custom invert function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Ruby class Hash has method "invert" which make "reversal" between keys and values and delete same keys (in our case its: "1=>:a"). 
    h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1} 
    => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1} 
    h.invert 
    => {1=>:c, 2=>:b}

How implement custom Hash method "c_invert", which will return very first (not last) pair of duplicated key => value? Exapmle:

```
> h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1} 
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1} 
> h.c_invert 
=> {1=>:a, 2=>:b}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Hash
  def c_invert
    Hash[to_a.reverse].invert
  end
end
```

or

```
class Hash
  def c_invert
    Hash[to_a.reverse.map(&:reverse)]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h =  {:d =>1,:a=>1, :b=> 2, :c=>1}
Hash[h.map(&:reverse).reverse]
# => {1=>:d, 2=>:b}

h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1} 
Hash[h.map(&:reverse).reverse]
# => {1=>:a, 2=>:b}
```